# C array of struct

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct Expected {

   const int number;
   const char operand;

} Expected;   

Expected array[1];
Expected e = {1, 'c'};
array[0] = e;
```

I don't understand why you cannot add to a struct array like that.  Do I have to calculate the positions in memory myself?

Comment: What error message does the compiler give you?

Comment: You try to modify a const value ?

Comment: assignment of read-only location 'array[0]'

Comment: Make the members non constant for a start.

Comment: When you say "add to a struct array" are you talking about making the array bigger, or changing an existing value? That would be better written as "assign to a struct array".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The element of `Expected` are declared `const`.  That means they can't be modified.

In order to set the values, you need to *initialize* them at the time the variable is defined:

```
Expected array[1] = { {1, 'c'} };
```

The fact that you're using an array doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Making the struct members `const` means you can't write to them.
After removing that it works.

```
typedef struct Expected {

   int number;
   char operand;

} Expected;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not allowed because `struct` has `const` members:

> error: assignment of read-only location `array[0]`
>
> ```
> array[0] = e;
> ```

When a `struct` has one `const` member, the whole `struct` cannot be assigned as well.

If it were possible to assign array elements like that, one would be able to circumvent const-ness of any member of a `struct` like this:

```
Expected replacement = {.number = array[0].number, .operand = newOperand}; // << Allowed
array[0] = replacement; // <<== This is not allowed
```

Compiler flags this assignment as an error ([demo](https://ideone.com/ITGTqP)).

If you need to keep `const`, you would have to construct your array with initializers instead of using assignments.